# Least square derivatives

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, least-squares, gradient-descent

Let $X_1, \ldots, X_N \in \mathbb{R}^p$ and $Y_1, \ldots, Y_N \in \mathbb{R}$. Define
$$
X=\left[\begin{array}{c}
X_1^{\top} \\
\vdots \\
X_N^{\top}
\end{array}\right] \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times p}, \quad Y=\left[\begin{array}{c}
Y_1 \\
\vdots \\
Y_N
\end{array}\right] \in \mathbb{R}^N
$$

Let
$$
\ell_i(\theta)=\frac{1}{2}\left(X_i^{\top} \theta-Y_i\right)^2 \quad \text { for } i=1, \ldots, N, \quad \mathcal{L}(\theta)=\frac{1}{2}\|X \theta-Y\|^2 .
$$

Show (a) $\nabla_\theta \ell_i(\theta)=\left(X_i^{\top} \theta-Y_i\right) X_i$ and (b) $\nabla_\theta \mathcal{L}(\theta)=X^{\top}(X \theta-Y)$.

Hint. For part (a), start by computing $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j} \ell_i(\theta)$. For part (b), use the fact that
$$
M v=\sum_{i=1}^N M_{:, i} v_i \in \mathbb{R}^p
$$
for any $M \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times N}, v \in \mathbb{R}^N$, where $M_{:, i}$ is the $i$ th column of $M$ for $i=1, \ldots, N$.

My Preliminary Progress:
For part (a): I started with the definition of $\ell_i(\theta)$ and applied the chain rule to compute the gradient, arriving at:
$$
\nabla_\theta \ell_i(\theta)=\left(X_i^{\top} \theta-Y_i\right) X_i
$$

For part (b): Using the overall loss $\mathcal{L}(\theta)$, I leveraged matrix differentiation rules and the hint provided regarding matrix-vector multiplication to deduce that:
$$
\nabla_\theta \mathcal{L}(\theta)=X^{\top}(X \theta-Y)
$$

My Questions:

1. Rigorous Derivation: Could someone provide a step-by-step, rigorous derivation of both (a) and (b), possibly highlighting any subtleties in matrix calculus that I might have glossed over?
2. Matrix Calculus Techniques: Are there specific matrix calculus techniques or identities that are particularly useful in simplifying these derivations?
3. Generalization: How might these results generalize to other loss functions or optimization problems within machine learning?

I believe that understanding these derivations in depth will greatly enhance my comprehension of optimization in statistical learning. Thank you in advance for your time and help!

Comment: one question per post, please. Here you ask three.  Edit your post to focus on *the most pressing question* you have.

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\R#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\L{{\cal L}}
\def\t{\theta}
\def\k{\otimes}
\def\h{\tfrac12\:}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
$Here are a few things that I find very helpful for *Matrix Calculus* problems.

The *Frobenius Product* is denoted by a colon and will help you avoid silly transposition errors.

It has the following properties
$$\eqalign{
A,B&\in\R{m\times n}\qquad X\in\R{m\times p}\qquad Y\in\R{p\times n} \\
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
B:B &= \frob{B}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
A:B &= B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \\
\LR{XY}:B &= X:\LR{BY^T} \;=\; Y:\LR{X^TB} \\
A:B &= I_m\!:\LR{BA^T} \;=\; I_n:\LR{A^TB} \\
}$$
Next is the *differential* of $\L$, which is denoted as ${d\L}$ and defined in terms of the gradient $\gradLR{\L}{X}$ and the differential $dX$ (which obeys the same rules of *Matrix Algebra* as $X$ itself)
$$\eqalign{
d\L &= \gradLR{\L}{X}:dX \\
}$$
Using differentials allows you to avoid the awkward matrix-by-matrix and matrix-by-vector gradients which are often required by the *Chain Rule*.

Next are the *standard basis* vectors $\{e_i\}$ and matrices $\{E_{jk}\}$ whose components are all $0$ except for the one component indicated by the subscripts, which equals $\o$. Interestingly they are also the component-wise$\;$self-gradients of an arbitrary vector or matrix
variable
$$\eqalign{
\grad x{x_i} = e_i \qquad\qquad \grad X{X_{jk}} = E_{jk} 
}$$
In your problem, note that
$$\eqalign{
e_k^T\LR{X\t-Y} = \LR{X_k^T\t-Y_k} \\
}$$
Let's examine your cost functions using the above notation
$$\eqalign{
\ell_k
 &= \h e_k^T\LR{X\t-Y}:e_k^T\LR{X\t-Y} \\
 &= \h e_ke_k^T:\LR{X\t-Y}\LR{X\t-Y}^T \\
 &= \h E_{kk}:\LR{X\t-Y}\LR{X\t-Y}^T \\
\\
\L
 &= \h \LR{X\t-Y}:\LR{X\t-Y} \\
 &= \h I :\LR{X\t-Y}\LR{X\t-Y}^T \\
 &= \LR{\sum_{k=\o}^N \h E_{kk}}:\LR{X\t-Y}\LR{X\t-Y}^T \;\equiv\; \sum_{k=\o}^N \ell_k \\
}$$
As you can see, the functions are closely related.

I'll do a step-by-step calculation for one of them and leave the other to you.

For typing convenience, define the matrix variable
$$\eqalign{
M &= \LR{X\t-Y} \qiq \c{dM = X\,d\t} \\
}$$
Then
$$\eqalign{
\L &= \h M:M \\
d\L
 &= \h dM:M \;+\; \h M:dM \\
 &= M:\c{dM} \\
 &= M:\c{X\,d\t} \\
 &= X^TM:d\t \\
 &= X^T\LR{X\t-Y}:d\t \\
\grad{\L}{\t} &= X^T\LR{X\t-Y} \\
}$$